# Как правильно составить условие для rewritecond?

Tags: .htaccess

Мне нужно сделать переадресацию с адреса

> site.ru/get/g/(.*)/

на

> site.ru/country/(.*)/

Но при условии что после (.*) ничего нет. 
То-есть если ссылка будет типа:

> site.ru/get/g/(.*)/f/(.*)

то ничего не делать.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^get/g/([^/]+)/?$ /country/$1/ [L,NC,R=301]
```